# awk to add text to file based on coordinates

Tags: awk

In the below `awk` (which executes but produces an empty output) I am using the `$4` in `file1` as a unique id and reading each `$1`, `$2`, and `$3` value into a variable `chr`, `min`, and `max`.

The `$4` is then split on the `_` in `file2` and read into `array`. Each value in the split will match a `$4` id in `file1` The `chr` needs to match the `$1`, the `min` and `max` must be between the `$2` and `$3` values in `file2`.

An exact match is not needed rather just that the `min` or `max` variables falls within `$2` and `$3`. If that is true then `exon` is printed in `$5` of `file1`, if it is not true then `intron` is printed in `$5`.

The desired output has the `exon/intron` added to it but there is another part where the values in `$2` or `$3` are adjusted but I am trying to script that before I ask. I am not sure if the below is the best way but hopefully it is a start. Thank you :).

**file1**  `tab delimited` except for whitespace after `$3` and `$4`

```
chr7    94027591    94027701    COL1A2
chr6    31980068    31980074    TNXB
```

**file2**  `tab delimited`

```
chr7    94027059    94027070    COL1A2_cds_1_0_chr7_94027060_f  0   +
chr7    94027693    94027708    COL1A2_cds_2_0_chr7_94027694_f  0   +
chr6    32009125    32009227    TNXB_cds_0_0_chr6_32009126_r    0   -
chr6    32009547    32009711    TNXB_cds_1_0_chr6_32009548_r    0   -
```

**desired output**

```
chr7    94027683    94027701    COL1A2    exon
chr6    31980068    31980074    TNXB    intron
```

**awk w/ comments**

```
awk '
FNR==NR{ open block process matching line in file 1 and file2
 a[$4];  # use as a key with unique id
 chr[$4]=$1;  # store $1 value in chr
 min[$4]=$2;  # store $2 value in min
 max[$4]=$3;  # store $3 value in max
  next  # process next line
}  # close block
{  # open block
 split($4,array,"_");  # spilt $4 on underscore
 print $0,(array[1] in a) &&  ($2<=min[array[1]] && $2<=max[array[1] &&  $1=chr[array[1]])?"exon":"intron"
}' file1 OFS="\t" file2 > output  # close block, mention input with field separators and output
```

Comment: Are you sure your expected output if mentioned correctly here? By logic it should be Input_file2's values should be targeted to print in final output. Could you please confirm once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, your shown final output is NOT looking correct by logic, since Input_file2 has multiple entries and Input_file1 has only single ones(I am going by samples shown only). Could you please check this one once? If any changes in your output or logic then please do mention them clearly.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  SUBSEP=","
}
FNR==NR{
  max[$1,$NF]=$3
  min[$1,$NF]=$2
  next
}
{
  split($4,array,"_")
}
(($1,array[1]) in max){
  if(($2>min[array[5],array[1]] && $2<max[array[5],array[1]]) || ($3>max[array[5],array[1]] && $3<max[array[5],array[1]])){
     print array[5],array[1],min[array[5],array[1]],max[array[5],array[1]],"exon"
     next
  }
}
{
  print $0,"intron"
}'  Input_file1   Input_file2  | column -t
```

What this command is doing it is checking Input_file2's 2nd field OR 3rd field either they are coming in range of Input_file1's 2nd and 3rd field. If anyone of them is coming then I am printing Input_file1's output adding `exon` in it or else printing Input_file2's output adding `intron` string at last of it.

Comment: Works perfect.... thank you (I apologize for the input typo its early) :)

Comment: @cm0728, not an issue, please correct your sample expected output in your post so that people who are seeing this thread could understand question and its answer more clearly. Keep  sharing and keep posting on this great site.