# awk search file may contain multiple entries of id

Tags: awk

The `awk` below works perfect, thanks to @RavinderSingh13, if the id in `$4` (like in f) is unique. However most of my data is like `f1` where the same id can appear multiple times. I think that is the reason why the `awk` is not working as expected. I added a comment on the line that I can not change without causing the script to abort. Each line in `f2` is searched and must contain the id, in this case `COL1A2` but that id may not be a single entry. That is the id may appear 5 times, but each line with that is in `f2` is searched. Using the `$4` in `f1` as the id and reading each `$1`, `$2`, and `$3` value into a variable `min` and `max`.

The `$4` is then split on the `_` in `f2` and read into `array`. The same id from `f1` may appear in multiple lines of `f2` however each will have unique `$2` and `$3` values. Each value in the split will match a `$4` id in `f1`. The `min` and `max` must match the `$1` of `f2` and be between the `$2` and  `$3` values in `f2`. An exact match is not needed rather just that the `min` or `max` variables falls within `$2` and `$3`. If that is true then `exon` is printed in `$5` of `f2` if it is not true then `intron` is printed in `$5`. Most of this works as expected I just did not account for the possibity for multiple enteries and am nut sure how to adjust for it. Thank you :)

For example using the contents of the `f1` where `COL1A2` appears 3 times, each entry or line is searched in `f2`. Currently, I believe since `COL1A2` is not unique not match is found in `f2` as the `min` and `max` are not set per entry or line. Thank you :).

**awk w/ desired output**

```
awk '
 BEGIN{
  SUBSEP=","
}
FNR==NR{
  max[$1,$NF]=$3
  min[$1,$NF]=$2
  next
}
{
 split($4,array,"_")   # How do I change/modify this so it only looks a each line with this id `COL1A2` in it?
}
(($1,array[1]) in max){
if(($2>min[array[5],array[1]] && $2<max[array[5],array[1]]) || ($3>max[array[5],array[1]] && $3<max[array[5],array[1]])){
  print array[5],array[1],min[array[5],array[1]],max[array[5],array[1]],"exon"
  next
}
}
{
  print $0,"intron"}' f f2 

chr7    94024333    94024423    COL1A2_cds_0_0_chr7_94024344_f  0   + intron
chr7    94027049    94027080    COL1A2_cds_1_0_chr7_94027060_f  0   + intron
chr7 COL1A2 94027591 94027701 exon
```

**awk w/ current output**

```
  .... }' f1 f2

chr7    94024333    94024423    COL1A2_cds_0_0_chr7_94024344_f  0   + intron
chr7    94027049    94027080    COL1A2_cds_1_0_chr7_94027060_f  0   + intron
chr7    94027683    94027718    COL1A2_cds_2_0_chr7_94027694_f  0   + intron
```

**contents of f** `single COL1A2 entry`

```
chr7    94027591    94027701    COL1A2
```

**contents of f1**  `multiple COL1A2 entry, this is most of the actual data, very few are single entries though there are some`

```
chr7    94027591    94027701    COL1A2  
chr7    94027799    94027811    COL1A2  
chr7    94030799    94030847    COL1A2
```

**contents of f2** `always the same format`

```
chr7    94024333    94024423    COL1A2_cds_0_0_chr7_94024344_f  0   +
chr7    94027049    94027080    COL1A2_cds_1_0_chr7_94027060_f  0   +
chr7    94027683    94027718    COL1A2_cds_2_0_chr7_94027694_f  0   +
```

Comment: The `awk` version is  `GNU Awk 4.0.1`

Comment: Is this a continuation to an older entry where you explained the problem? Sorry, I don't understand the meaning of the different lines in f1 and how you want the other lines in f1 (after the first one) to be treated.

Comment: Yes it is a continuation from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54218022/awk-to-add-text-to-file-based-on-coordinates and different lines in `f1` is that eventhough the id in ~$4` or `COL1A21` is the same each line has a unique `$2` or a separate entry. Thank you :).

Comment: Create a question that make sense standalone unless you only want answers from people willing to look back through old posts or other links to piece together what it is you're asking about. Also make sure all relevant information is contained in the question, not spread out through comments.

Comment: I made an edit to the post to include all the details and hopefully make it more clear/ make more sense. Thank you very much :).

Comment: Your description and samples are still vague. It's better to use small, intuitive samples than lengthy text. And use pictures when samples are not intuitive enough, is better still.

Comment: I made an update to the post to detail things better. Thank you :).